# The date of birth on the US visa is different from the date of birth on the passport

Tags: visas, usa

I have had a US visa for a few years and have been travelling for work purposes for a couple of years now. However, I recently discovered that the date of birth on the visa is different from the one in my passport: my birthday is in June but on the visa it has being printed out as July. I am worried about what the embassy will say and think when I tell them about it. Will they be angry and cancel my visa since I have used it to enter the US?

This was an honest mistake and I should have discovered it earlier. Can someone please share any advice or experiences of similar circumstances? I am worried that I will not be able to use the visa anymore and could end up in trouble.

Comment: What is your correct date of birth and what is shown on the visa? I ask 'cos (for instance) in the UK we show 4th July 1970 as 04/07/70 but in the USA it's shown as 07/04/70.

Comment: My birthday is in June but on the visa it has being printed out as July 

Comment: @canonacer nice try, but on a US visa the date you mention would be shown as `04JUL1970`, so there isn't really much room for confusion.

Comment: Why should they be angry with you if it's their fault to begin with? Even if you had provided the wrong date in your application, it's something that should have been flagged when compared to your passport. I would worry about the timing for getting a fixed VISA reissued, or COVID-19 related travel bans interfering with that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice people I hope they will understand that it has been an honest mistake

Comment: If you've already traveled using the visa, it sounds like it's not a concern or it would have come up already.  As your birth date is printed in the passport, it's not as if they can pretend it's _your_ mistake.  If anyone brings it up, I'd just politely point out that it's a mistake and the correct date is printed in your passport.

Comment: @Kyralessa Past performance does not guarantee future results.  Immigration personal have a wide range of options when admitting someone to a country and each transaction you complete with them is a separate and distinct occasion.  So while one official may gloss over the difference and let you in, another official may look and go "WTF is this discrepancy?" and not admit you (or admit you after being held for hours).

Comment: "Hi I have had a us visa for a few years and have only recently travelled for work purposes and back again a few times for a couple of years now."  You're technically right, @PeterM, but technically anything could happen anywhere at any time.  To me it seems reasonable to surmise that if "a few times for a couple of years" this birth date discrepancy wasn't a problem, then it's not suddenly going to become a problem.  If it's a genuine problem then how did so many border agents miss it?

Comment: @Kyralessa That the discrepancy hasn't been noticed is a separate issue, but previously successfully traversing immigration doesn't negate that an issue exists. And for anecdotes I was once hassled at a US embassey when picking up a visa because even though it had been granted the embassy employee on the spot didn't like the way my application looked and almost didn't issue the visa.  And I was once detained at LAX because the immigration guy didn't like how my valid visa looked in my passport. So I am wary of situations where documentation is not correct.

Comment: Do you have time to apply for a new visa before your next trip to the US?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.